# How do I call this function in inline ASM? (MSVC++)

Tags: c++, assembly, inline, calling-convention

```
void __usercall sub_101A7850@<eax>(int a1@<edx>, int a2@<ecx>, int a3, int a4, int a5, int a6)
```

My first attempt (crashes):

```
__declspec(naked) void __stdcall callit(const int& a1, const int& a2, unsigned int a3, const int *a4, int a5, int *a6)
    {
        // void __usercall sub_101A7850@<eax>(int a1@<edx>, int a2@<ecx>, int a3, int a4, int a5, int a6)
        __asm
        {
            mov ecx, [esp + 4] // a1
            mov edx, [esp + 8] // a2
            push [esp + 12] // a3
            push [esp + 16] // a4
            push [esp + 20] // a5
            push [esp + 24] // a6
            call funcaddr
            retn 24
        }
    }
```

I have verified funcaddr is valid. Pretty sure its a __fastcall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have exchanged `ecx` and `edx`: your func signature says `a1<edx>` but you put `a1` into `ecx` and `a2` to `edx`.

Moreover: After pushing `a3` the `esp` relative offset for `a4` becomes 4 bytes farther. After pushing `a4` the `esp` relative offset for `a5` becomes 8 bytes farther, and so on... (so the correct offsets are: `a4`: `[esp+20]`, `a5`: `[esp+28]`, `a6`: `[esp+36]`)